# Given a metrizable topological space $(X,\tau)$, how to construct a metric that induces $\tau$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I need to show that $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ in the dictionary order topology is metrizable. So I need to find a metric that induces the dictionary order topology on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. I saw some solutions online. But they give a metric without any explanations on how did they come up with this metric.

I'd like to know a general way to construct a metric that induces a given topology if the topological space is metrizable.

Comment: I think the wording of your question might not say what you intend. It reads like "what is a general approach for all (or most) metrizable spaces?" (much harder than your dictionary order question), but I wonder if you just want tips for approaching problems like this one in an undergraduate topology course/textbook.

Comment: There are many solutions online for this question. But I don't know how did they construct metrics that work. So I want to know is there a general way to construct these metrics? Tips for approaching problems like this one are definitely welcome, and I appreciate it.

Comment: I haven't done it much myself, so take this with a grain of salt. If I have some geometric intuition about the space, I would use that first (e.g. can it be embedded in some sense in a known metric space?). Maybe there's some kind of conceptual similarity to another metric, and I would definitely investigate adapting the metric from the other space. Otherwise, I would concentrate on local bases of neighbourhoods, and try figuring out which ones I can identify with balls. But, in general, it's not an easy problem.

Comment: @TheoBendit It seems that there isn't a general way to construct this metric. I will try to use your method. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I don't think there is. If you think about how many wildly different equivalent metrics one can construct on a given metric space, it seems unlikely that there is one "canonical" one that an algorithm could construct.

Answer (score 0):

There is in fact a sort of procedure, if you can apply a standard metrisation theorem like Bing-Nagata-Smirnov (or easier: Urysohn) using special bases. But that's not the idea with the lexicographical plane. There you must get a feel for the space: small neighbourhoods of a point $(x,y)$ are of the form $\{x\} \times (y-r, y+r)$, because keeping the $x$-coordinate constant keeps you "close". Such an interval shows (as it hits no other vertical lines) that all verticals are open and closed sets, so the plane is now very disconnected, and e.g. $(\frac{1}{n}, 0)$ does not converge to $(0,0)$ as it does usually.

So we have a disjoint "sum" of vertical copies of the real line and this gives rise to a metric in an easy way: just give two points with different $x$-coordinates distance $1$ and all horizontal lines as discrete topological/metric spaces and see that $\mathbb{R} \times_l \mathbb{R} \simeq (\mathbb{R}, D) \times (\mathbb{R}, d)$, where $D$ is the discrete metric and $d$ the Euclidean one, which is metrisable as a product of two metric spaces.

Comment: I think you'd have to compress the metric on each copy of $\mathbb{R}$ to have each distance less than 2 at most, in order to keep the triangle inequality working.  So, something like the standard tricks of using $\frac{d}{1+d}$ or $\min(d, 1)$ instead of $d$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Or the sum metric of the discrete and the usual one.